# Confusion with the phrase 'Under what circumstances'

Tags: expressions, construction

Below is what is causing me a lot of confusion.

Say, I did a test, and will have to redo it if I get below a certain mark, and I want to pose a question asking what mark it is (Or there might be other reasons that I need to redo the test) Can I say:

- Under what circumstances/In what situation will I have to resit the test?

However, it is kind of weird and ambiguous if I rearrange the sentence a little, like this;

- What circumstances will I have to do the test under?
- I will have to do the test under what circumstances?

It feels like the meaning completely changed from HOW BAD MY MARK HAVE TO BE, to asking THE SET OF CONDITIONS I HAVE TO DO THE TEST IN.

I have looked up some 'under what circumstances' clauses, but all of them seem to be perfectly logical even when rearranged. E.g. Under what circumstances is cheating a crime.

Is the wording of my question awkward/ambiguous? If so how can I make it better?
Or is the question perfectly fine under I rearranged it?

Many thanks

Comment: Say *"Under what circumstances will I have to resit the test?"*  The others are not idiomatic, and "What circumstances will I have to do the test under?" sounds too much like "What conditions will I have to do the test under?", to which the answer might be "No talking or communication, no mobile phones."

Comment: Juncinator, nice question! Have you done anything to research this yourself? If you have can you briefly mention what you have done at the bottom of your question. http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask it will help attract better qualitiy responses, it needn't be very long, just a brief statement about what you have done to research this already and what sources you used (if any)

Comment: What @Max said. Because the alternatives are "non-idiomatic", we naturally tend to look for a possible alternative meaning (why *else* would you use unusual phrasing?). The obvious alternative sense is *How will the resit be conducted?* (which automatically carries the implication that we *know* the test will be retaken).

Comment: Just adding a little to @Gary's comment, which may be useful if you have more questions: the primary expectation regarding *research* is to use the *site*'s search bar found in the top right corner of the page (not necessarily google searches), plus dictionaries. This is because Stack Exchange is intended to be a repository of expert answers. You may well find what you're looking for in the repository already.

Answer (score -1):

Why say resit ? Can't one take the test standing ?

I shall say as below :

**Kindly state the circumstances under which  I may have to take the test again ?**

Comment: "resit" is a perfectly normal way to say "take an examination again", there's no need to take issue with that choice of word.

Comment: I agree with @MaxWilliams. "Resitting" an exam is a British-English version of American-English "retaking an exam."